# JAVA: Runtime Exception (I think that's what i need to use)

Tags: java, windows, swing

Ok, I need my program to validate user entered data.  If that data is invalid, the program needs to skip almost all of my code and get to the end of my while loop to ask if the user would like to proceed with calculating another loan.  My professor has not provided us with a method of doing this and all the information ive found on the internet is not specific enough to help me.  Once again, I need the code after the validation to be skipped without exiting the program and go to the end of the loop where I ask the user if they want to calculate another loan.  Here is my code thus far.

```
        /*  This program is an extension of the previous Interest Calculator.  The only different is this one can
    compute not only simple interest but daily and monthly compound interest using a switch statement to
    differentiate each type of interest.    */

import javax.swing.*;
// Import the GUI methods
public class InterestCalculatorLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Entry point of program
        String again = "yes";
        while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes" ))
        {
            String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which type of loan would you like to find interest for? \n1 = Simple Interest \n2 = Monthly Compounded Interest \n3 = Daily Compounded Interest");
            int optionInt = Integer.parseInt(option);
            int interestType = Integer.parseInt(option);
            String paString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the principal amount");
            double pa = Double.parseDouble(paString);
            double interest = 0;
            double months = 0;
            double totalInterest = 0;
            double years = 0;
            final double daysInYear = 365.0;
            final double daysInMonth = 30.41666666667;
            final double monthsInYear = 12.0;

            // Logic statements to validate user input or otherwise run through the rest of the program without calculation
            if (pa <= 0)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Error: The principal amount must be greater than zero.  You entered " + pa);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String interestString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter The Annual Interest Rate [1 - 100 percent]) ");
                interest = Double.parseDouble(interestString);
            }
                if (interest < 0 || interest > 100)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Error: The interest amount must be between 1 and 100. You entered " + interest);
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    String monthsString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the number of months");
                    months = Double.parseDouble(monthsString);
                }
                    if (months <= 0)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Error: The number of months must be above 0.  You entered " + months);
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        switch (optionInt)
                        {
                        // Case for simple intrest
                        case 1: optionInt = 1;
                            months = months/monthsInYear;
                            totalInterest = pa * (interest/100.0) * months;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total amount of interest of your loan is $" + totalInterest + ".");
                            break;

                        // Case for monthly compounded interest
                        case 2: optionInt = 2;
                            interest = interest/100.0;
                            years = months/monthsInYear;
                            double exponent = months*years;
                            double interestOverMonths = 1+interest/months;
                            double thirdTotal = Math.pow(interestOverMonths, exponent);
                            double secondTotal = pa*thirdTotal;
                            totalInterest = secondTotal - pa;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total amount of interest of your loan is $" + totalInterest + ".");
                            break;

                        // Case for daily compounded interest
                        case 3: optionInt = 3;
                            interest = interest/100.0;
                            double days = months*daysInMonth;
                            years = days/daysInYear;
                            exponent = days*years;
                            double interestOverDays = 1+interest/days;
                            thirdTotal = Math.pow(interestOverDays, exponent);
                            secondTotal = pa*thirdTotal;
                            totalInterest = secondTotal - pa;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total amount of interest of your loan is $" + totalInterest + ".");
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to compute another loan? (yes or no)");

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is a try/catch block, combined with throwing an exception. There is CRAP LOADS of examples on the net but probably best to check out the Tutorials first at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Use a separate method and an if statement.

Comment: FYI, your indentation is misleading, as you keep adding extra indents for non-nested if-then statements.  It would help if you cleaned that up a bit

Comment: Not related at all but you can refactor your code and divide it into several methods.

Answer (score 1):

Break is very useful for stopping loops as you said you wanted. Essentially it has the effect of setting the boolean parameter of a for loop to true.

You can of course, use what in CMD is referred to a GOTO. you can create something like:

```
top:
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(i == 9){
    break top;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Of course it is, and it is a basic Java function. I'm surprised it wasn't recommended more.

Comment: I thought we passed the age of goto statements decades ago... And your example to support it isn't helping; why not just set the condition to i < 9? And "break top" makes it sound like you're breaking _to_ top rather than after the loop associated with it. I wouldn't say it's unreadable but it's a lot less readable than it should be. The feature probably still exists to maintain backwards compatibility or something with ancient Java versions.

Comment: thx @Hedja. I hoped someone would come with such a statement. I was afraid to be the only anti-goto-return advocate.

Answer (score 1):

I've skimmed through your code and to be honest, I don't know much about loans and the calculations associated with it.

As you're clearly still learning the basics, a simple solution by the looks of it would be to take out:

```
while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes" ))
{

    /*
     * FROM HERE
     */
    String option = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Which type of loan would you like to find interest for? \n1 = Simple Interest \n2 = Monthly Compounded Interest \n3 = Daily Compounded Interest");
    int optionInt = Integer.parseInt(option);

    //...

    /*
    *  TO HERE
    */
    again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to compute another loan? (yes or no)");

}
```

And put it in its own method called for example:

```
public static void askAndProcessDetails()
```

So when you `return` you will go to the repeat dialogue.

```
while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes" ))
{
    askAndProcessDetails();
    again = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like to compute another loan? (yes or no)");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

continue is maybe one of the worse feature of java, with the break keyword (except in switch statements). It leads to jigsaw code where you have to find out where the code jumps. One continue *may* be practical but it gets very hard to change the code it produces (think about adding an inner loop..), and 2 continues will make you crazy.

You can always avoid using continue, there is always another solution. Same for break.

Here, why don't you just use some kind of

```
if( answerIsValid ) {
  //process it
  ...
}//if
```

That's easy, simple, clear and even better when you have a separate method that contains processing.

Also, in your case, that is tied to robustness, you could provide a process() method that throws an exception if the data entered is not valid. This makes it even more clear that there is a "normal" program behavior and a bunch of strange cases you handle as errors.

```
public void processAnswer( String stringAnswer ) throws ArithmeticException {
   int answer = Integer.parseInt( stringAnswer );
     //rest of processing
     ...
}//met
```

then your main loop becomes

```
    String again = "yes";
    while (again.equalsIgnoreCase("yes" ))
    {
       String stringAnswer = JOptionPane...
       try {
         process( stringAnswer );
       } catch( ArithmeticException ex ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( "This is not an integer !" );
       }//catch
    }//while
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback some of it has been very useful already!  And yes I know my code is probably flawed I literally JUST started programming and learning Java so it's all very new to me.  I understand this entire program could have been broken up into several methods but I'm still learning how to do all that.